# Solution check to method of characteristic

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

After an attempt, I arrived at; $\quad u(x(t),y(t))=t+F(x-t)$.

Instead, the solution is; $\quad u(x(t),y(t))=y+F(x-y)$

Where have I possibly went wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

From a typical method of solving first order pde equations the pde $u_{x} + u_{y} = 1$ can be placed into the characteristic equations
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{1} = \frac{du}{1}.
\end{align}
Solving the $x-y$ set reveals
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{1} = \frac{dy}{1} \hspace{5mm} \rightarrow \hspace{5mm} dx - dy = 0 \hspace{5mm} \rightarrow \hspace{5mm} x - y = c_{1}.
\end{align}
Solving the $y-u$ set reveals
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{1} = \frac{du}{1} \hspace{5mm} \rightarrow \hspace{5mm} du - dy = 0 \hspace{5mm} \rightarrow \hspace{5mm} u - y = c_{2}.
\end{align}
Now combining the two equations the general solution is of the form $u(x,y) = y + G(x-y)$. Applying the initial condition that $u(x,0) = f(x)$ then leads to $G(x) = f(x)$ and thus the solution being $u(x,y) = y + f(x-y)$